# MS Access SQL: Get datasets with highest versions and revisions

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a database table with (for this question) three columns:

1. Document ID
2. Revison
3. Version

Each document has got 1..n Revisions and each Revision has got 1..n Versions.

What is my SQL statement for all Documents in their highest Revisions and the highest Versions of these revisions?

```
Doc Title   Revision   Version    Should be selected
Dok 1       01         01
Dok 1       01         02
Dok 1       01         03         
Dok 1       02         01
Dok 1       02         02         * Because Rev 02 / V02 is the highest
Dok 2       01         01
Dok 2       02         01
Dok 2       03         01         * Because Rev 03 / V01 is the highest
```

D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a unique id for each *row* (which I recommend for all tables), then a correlated subquery is the way to go:

```
select d.*
from documents as d
where d.pk = (select top (1) d2.pk
              from documents as d2
              where d2.documentid = d.documentid
              order by d2.version desc, d2.revision desc, d2.pk desc
             );
```

Without a primary key, you can do this by concatenating the values together:

```
select d.*
from documents as d
where d.version & "-" & d.revision =
          (select top (1) d2.version & "-" & d2.revision
           from documents as d2
           where d2.documentid = d.documentid
           order by d2.version desc, d2.revision desc
          );
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use an max aggregation function and group by in join with a subquery

```
    select id,  max_ver, max(revision)
    from my_table  m
    inner join (
        select ID, max(version) max_ver
        from my_table
        group by id  
    ) t on t.id = m.id and t.max_ver = m.version
    group by  id,  max_ver
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a table name of `Table1` (change to suit), I would suggest the following:

```
SELECT 
    Table1.[Document ID],
    Table1.Revision,
    Max(Table1.Version) As Version
FROM
    Table1 INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT 
            Table1.[Document ID], 
            Max(Table1.Revision) AS Rev
        FROM 
            Table1
        GROUP BY 
            Table1.[Document ID]
    ) DocRev
    ON 
    Table1.[Document ID] = DocRev.[Document ID] AND 
    Table1.Revision = DocRev.Rev
GROUP BY 
    Table1.[Document ID],
    Table1.Revision
```

Here, the nested `SELECT` query first obtains the greatest `Revision` for each `Document ID`:

```
SELECT 
    Table1.[Document ID], 
    Max(Table1.Revision) AS Rev
FROM 
    Table1
GROUP BY 
    Table1.[Document ID]
```

This is then `INNER JOIN`ed to the original table to obtain all `Version` records for each maximum `Revision`, with the maximum `Version` record finally output to the result.