# Delete datasets with NOT highest versions and revisions

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to complete the OPPOSITE of [MS Access SQL: Get datasets with highest versions and revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53034071/ms-access-sql-get-datasets-with-highest-versions-and-revisions/53034548#53034548)

I have a database table with (for this question) four columns:

1. ID
2. Document Number
3. Revison
4. Version

Each document has got 1..n Revisions and each Revision has got 1..n Versions.

What is my SQL statement for DELETING Documents where

- either the same Document No and the same revision, but a higher version exist
- or the same Document No and a higher revision exist (including all versions)

  ```
  ID  Doc-No Rev Vers Should be deleted?
  1   Dok1   01  01   yes, because same Doc-No higher rev exists
  2   Dok1   01  02   yes, because same Doc-No higher rev exists
  3   Dok1   01  03   yes, because same Doc-No higher rev exists
  4   Dok1   02  01   yes, because same Doc-No and a higher vers for this rev exists
  5   Dok1   02  02   no, because Rev 02 / V02 is the highest for Doc-No Dok1
  6   Dok2   01  01   yes, because same Doc-No higher rev exists
  7   Dok2   02  01   yes, because same Doc-No higher rev exists
  8   Dok2   03  01   no, because Rev 03 / V01 is the highest for Doc-No Dok2
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original top revision and top version query would be more efficient with an `INNER JOIN` on a couple of aggregate queries for *revision* and *version* levels rather than a correlated subquery. The former calculates **once** for all rows in outer query and latter for *every* row:

```
SELECT d.*
FROM (documents d
INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT sub_d.[Doc-No], MAX(sub_d.Rev) AS max_rev
   FROM documents sub_d
   GROUP BY sub_d.[Doc-No]) AS agg1
ON d.[Doc-No] = agg1.[Doc-No]
AND d.Rev = agg1.max_rev)

INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT sub_d.[Doc-No], sub_d.Rev,
                          MAX(sub_d.Ver) AS max_ver
   FROM documents sub_d
   GROUP BY sub_d.[Doc-No], sub_d.Rev) AS agg2
ON d.[Doc-No] = agg2.[Doc-No]
AND d.Rev = agg2.rev    
AND d.Ver = agg2.max_ver
```

Which translates for `DELETE` as:

```
DELETE DISTINCTROW d.*
FROM (documents d
INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT sub_d.[Doc-No], MAX(sub_d.Rev) AS max_rev
   FROM documents sub_d
   GROUP BY sub_d.[Doc-No]) AS agg1
ON d.[Doc-No] = agg1.[Doc-No]
AND d.Rev = agg1.max_rev)

INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT sub_d.[Doc-No], sub_d.Rev,
                          MAX(sub_d.Ver) AS max_ver
   FROM documents sub_d
   GROUP BY sub_d.[Doc-No], sub_d.Rev) AS agg2
ON d.[Doc-No] = agg2.[Doc-No]
AND d.Rev = agg2.rev
AND d.Ver = agg2.max_ver
```

Comment: Your first example would not returns results if an earlier `revision` contains a later `version` than that of the latest `revision`, e.g. Rev 1 Ver 3 and also Rev 2 Ver 2; `Max(Rev) = 2`, `Max(Ver) = 3`, but this doesn't exist.

Comment: Good point @LeeMac. Adjusted accordingly with two agg query `JOIN`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
delete from t
    where t.id <> (select top (1) t2.id
                   from t as t2
                   where t2.doc_no = t.doc_num
                   order by t2.version desc, t2.revision desc, t2.id desc
                  );
```

Of course, back up the table before trying such a `delete`.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, but I get a Syntax Error when pasting that in m y MS Access SQL-Editor. At "where t2.doc_no = t.doc_num" I assume that doc_no and doc_num has to be both "Doc_No"?

Comment: @StefanMeyer . . . The query should indeed be using the actual names of the the columns and tables in your database.

Answer (score 0):

The following should achieve the desired result:

```
delete from Table1 t1 
where exists
(
    select 1 from Table1 t2 
    where
    t1.[Doc-No] = t2.[Doc-No] and 
    (
        t1.Rev < t2.Rev or 
       (t1.Rev = t2.Rev and t1.Vers < t2.Vers)
   )
)
```

(Change `Table` to the name of your table along with any other fields which don't match your data)

Always backup your data before running `delete` queries - there is no undo!